# How to disable inline of a Flexbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

#### Code

```js
<Box backgroundColor="#fdfdfd" p={6}>
    <Flex 
        justifyContent="center" 
        alignItems="center" 
        w="100%"
        mt={5}
    >
        <Heading textAlign="left" fontSize="1.5rem" mb={5} display="block">
            Những cán bộ của chúng tôi
        </Heading>
        {Data.map(userData => <UserInfo key={userData.id} data={userData} />)}
    </Flex>
</Box>
```

#### Web preview

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48d4Y.png)

#### Problem

The **`Heading`** is inline, but I don't want to be `inline`. Is there any way to disable it?

#### Edit

If I mode `Heading` above `Flex` then it will look like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgw9Z.png)

Comment: it's because u have to define flex-direction:column. this will keep your flex items(children in different lines like u need .

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the fact that the wrapper of the `Heading` component is a `Flex` box container. to make  `Heading` sit on it own `Row` You should wrap it inside a `Box` element and set attribute `w="100%"` like this

```
<Flex  wrap="wrap">
    <Box w="100%">
        <Heading textAlign="left" fontSize="1.5rem" mb={5} display="block">
            Những cán bộ của chúng tôi
        </Heading>
    </Box>

    // here will go the {Data.map...}
    <Box>
</Flex>
```

As `Box` will be a `flex item` sitting at the same level as `UserInfo` which are return from the `map` function. It will take the entire horizontal space available and all other elements will go underneath It.

You should add `wrap` attribute to the `Flex` Component so as the box take `100%` width available all other will go on a new line